# Mongodb .aggregate not matching $or?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Whether a user sends or receives a message, he/she should be able to archive the message for him/herself.

This .aggregate $or, however, only returns docs that the user is the recipient of ('to') that he/she has marked 'archive':'true'. It does accurately filter messages according to the 'value' Booleans.

```
Models.Messages.aggregate([

    // Match documents
    { "$match": {
      "$or" : [
          {
              "to": { 
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "username": 'userA',
                        "view.archive": true,
                        "view.bin": false
                    }
              }
          },
          {
              "from" : {
                  "$elemMatch" : {
                      "username" : 'userA',
                      "view.archive": true,
                      "view.bin": false
                  }
              }
          }
      ],
      "$or": [
               { 'value.1': true },
               { 'value.2': true },
               { 'value.3': true },
               { 'value.4': false } 
             ]
    }},

    // Unwind to de-normalize
    { "$unwind": "$to" },
    { "$unwind": "$from" },

    // Match the array elements      
    { "$match": {
       "to.username": 'userA',
       "to.view.archive": true,
       "from.username": 'userA',
       "from.view.archive": true
    }},

    // Group back all the elements of the original document
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "from": { "$push": "$from" },
       "to": { "$push": "$to" },
       "message": { "$first": "$message" },
       "updated": { "$first": "$updated" }
    }},

    // Sort by updated, most recent first (descending)
    {"$sort": {"updated": -1}}

], function (err, docs) {
```

How could this be altered so that all the fields of both of the following messages are aggregated for userA:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e83867f316ea7f22fd3b2b"),
    "updated" : ISODate("2014-08-11T03:29:06.000Z"),
    "message" : "message1",
    "value" : [
                "1" : true,
                "2" : false,
                "3" : false,
                "4" : false
            ]
    "to" : [ 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("53e835bd76e0d04318d8cc4e"),
            "username" : "userA",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53e83867f316ea7f22fd3b2c"),
            "view" : {
                "inbox" : false,
                "outbox" : false,
                "archive" : true,
                "bin" : false
            }
        }
    ],
    "from" : [ 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("53e8360276e0d04318d8cc55"),
            "username" : "userB",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53e83867f316ea7f22fd3b2d"),
            "view" : {
                "inbox" : false,
                "outbox" : true,
                "archive" : false,
                "bin" : false
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 5
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e83867f316ea7f22fd3b2b"),
    "updated" : ISODate("2014-08-11T03:29:06.000Z"),
    "message" : "message2",
    "value" : [
                "1" : false,
                "2" : true,
                "3" : false,
                "4" : false
            ]
    "to" : [ 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("53e8360276e0d04318d8cc55"),
            "username" : "userB",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53e83867f316ea7f22fd3b2c"),
            "view" : {
                "inbox" : true,
                "outbox" : false,
                "archive" : false,
                "bin" : false
            }
        }
    ],
    "from" : [ 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("53e835bd76e0d04318d8cc4e"),
            "username" : "userA",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53e83867f316ea7f22fd3b2d"),
            "view" : {
                "inbox" : false,
                "outbox" : true,
                "archive" : true,
                "bin" : false
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 5
}
```

Comment: What is the content of the "messagingQuery" variable in this statement? Very similar questions have been posted under another user account. Are you the same person? A co-worker? Or just looking for an answer to be provided for those questions?

Comment: You seem to have two `$or` fields in your `$match` object, which isn't valid.  You need to wrap those in an `$and` array if they both need to be satisfied.

Comment: @NeilLunn the messagingQuery is now replaced with the query details. Stack was my previous account, which I started when I just beginning programming, and I am determined to ask even better questions moving forward..so I'm starting fresh.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks for that. Would it look like this.. $or:[ $and: [ {to:..}{from:..} ] {value:..} ]

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two `$or` fields at the top level of your first `$match` object, so you need to wrap those in an `$and` array like the following if they both need to be satisfied:

```js
{ "$match": { 
  $and: [{
    "$or" : [
        {
            "to": { 
                  "$elemMatch": {
                      "username": 'userA',
                      "view.archive": true,
                      "view.bin": false
                  }
            }
        },
        {
            "from" : {
                "$elemMatch" : {
                    "username" : 'userA',
                    "view.archive": true,
                    "view.bin": false
                }
            }
        }
    ]}, {
    "$or": [
             { 'value.1': true },
             { 'value.2': true },
             { 'value.3': true },
             { 'value.4': false } 
           ]
    }
  ]
}}
```

There's a lot going on in your pipeline, so this may not be the only problem.

Comment: Thanks again for this. For some reason, the result is still excluding the $from results, so it's probably something else in the pipeline..