# MongoDB .find with multiple $or statements, syntax error 'unexpected token ]'?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

A user may send or receive a message, and should be able to archive his/her message regardless.

This .find should therefore return any docs where `userA` is in `to.username` or `from.username`, with `view.archive:true`. From there, the second $or should filter the results from the first $or to only include the matching docs where the message's `value.1:true`, `value.2:true`, or `value.3:true`

Right now, however, there is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]` for the closing ] on the first $or

```
Models.Messages.find(
   { 
        "$or" : [
            {
                "to": { 
                      "$elemMatch": {
                          "username": 'userA',
                          "view.archive": true,
                          "view.bin": true
                      }
                }
            },
            {
                "from" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                      "username" : 'userA',
                      "view.archive": true,
                      "view.bin": true
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
      "$or": [
               { 'value.1': true },
               { 'value.2': true },
               { 'value.3': true },
               { 'value.4': false } 
             ]
   }
).sort([['updated','descending']]).exec(function (err, messages) {
```

Both of these messages should be found for userA:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e83867f316ea7f22fd3b2b"),
    "updated" : ISODate("2014-08-11T03:29:06.000Z"),
    "message" : "message1",
    "value" : [
                "1" : true,
                "2" : false,
                "3" : false,
                "4" : false
            ]
    "to" : [ 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("53e835bd76e0d04318d8cc4e"),
            "username" : "userA",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53e83867f316ea7f22fd3b2c"),
            "view" : {
                "inbox" : false,
                "outbox" : false,
                "archive" : true,
                "bin" : false
            }
        }
    ],
    "from" : [ 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("53e8360276e0d04318d8cc55"),
            "username" : "userB",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53e83867f316ea7f22fd3b2d"),
            "view" : {
                "inbox" : false,
                "outbox" : true,
                "archive" : false,
                "bin" : false
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 5
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e83867f316ea7f22fd3b2b"),
    "updated" : ISODate("2014-08-11T03:29:06.000Z"),
    "message" : "message2",
    "value" : [
                "1" : false,
                "2" : true,
                "3" : false,
                "4" : false
            ]
    "to" : [ 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("53e8360276e0d04318d8cc55"),
            "username" : "userB",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53e83867f316ea7f22fd3b2c"),
            "view" : {
                "inbox" : true,
                "outbox" : false,
                "archive" : false,
                "bin" : false
            }
        }
    ],
    "from" : [ 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("53e835bd76e0d04318d8cc4e"),
            "username" : "userA",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53e83867f316ea7f22fd3b2d"),
            "view" : {
                "inbox" : false,
                "outbox" : true,
                "archive" : true,
                "bin" : false
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 5
}
```

Comment: you forgot to add $and before both $or filters

Comment: You're still (incorrectly) using multiple `$or` fields as in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236717/mongodb-aggregate-not-matching-or).  Did my answer there not make sense?

Comment: @JohnnyHK your answer there made complete sense..thanks for that. The result was still excluding the $from results, so it's probably something else in the pipeline.. So I decided to try out a .find instead, but thought $and was implied with .find

Comment: @soulcheck thanks for pointing that out..was under the impression that $and was implied with .find

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JohnnyHK for his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236717/mongodb-aggregate-not-matching-or/25246635#25246635) as it also applies here.

Was under the impression that $and was implied with .find in MongoDB, but when combining $or filters it appears to be necessary, as also pointed out by @soulcheck.

```
Models.Messages.find(
   { 
          $and: [{
            "$or" : [
                {
                    "to": { 
                          "$elemMatch": {
                              "username": 'userA',
                              "view.archive": true,
                              "view.bin": false
                          }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "from" : {
                        "$elemMatch" : {
                            "username" : 'userA',
                          "view.archive": true,
                          "view.bin": false
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]}, {
            "$or": [
                     { 'value.1': true },
                     { 'value.2': true },
                     { 'value.3': true },
                     { 'value.4': false } 
                   ]
            }
          ]
   }
).sort([['updated','descending']]).exec(function (err, messages) {
```